# Any reason to not put the Windows OS user app data folder on a separate drive/partition?

Tags: windows-7, disk-image, windows-backup

I currently have 2 hard drives on my Windows 7 PC.

- Windows OS and Software on an SSD drive
- Data on a regular 1tb drive

I now have to replace my SSD drive as it died however I also have another 2nd SSD drive so I now have 3 good drives.  2 SSDs and 1 data drive.

I am trying to find out if it is a bad idea to put my Windows `C:\Users\Username\AppData` folder on a separate drive than Windows is installed on?

This folder is updated daily from software so a backup image of my Windows drive would never have up to date data in that folder if I had to restore from a backup image.

I am just not sure if restoring from an older backup image with newer `C:\Users\Username\AppData` data would break anything or not.

Basically I am wanting to know what folders from Windows I should move to a separate drive to be able to restore from a backup image at anytime from an image that had just my Windows OS on it and maybe software too?  Same issue with the Windows paging file?

Any ideas/comments welcomed thanks

Comment: Besides the fact its not actually supported by Microsoft?  While it is possible to do it's not something Microsoft actually supports.

Comment: Even if you got it to work, it doesn't feel like a particularly sound practise. Just back the darn thing up. You'll appreciate it if you ever do need the backup.

Comment: Ok thanks for the comments I wasn't sure if it was a good idea or not, sounds like it's not!

Comment: While I agree that it's not supported by Microsoft, it's a shame since the `%TEMP%` folder actually lives inside `%AppData%` so you're essentially using your SSD as swap... Which is why I do it anyway, if you're careful and do it from the Windows installer prompt, it actually works quite fine.